# Postgres create trigger to emptying a table (daily)

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I've been research and found that we can't create a trigger to run once everyday. It requires something like cron.

Is there any other way? I have temporary table to store daily summerized data (items and total qty in a day) for a dashboard page. really need that to fasting my dashboard page. without that temp table every accessing the dashboard page, the query to create summerized data takes 90 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could use [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/include/doc.php?docset=1.4&docpage=pgagent.html). But what is wrong with a `cron` job?

Comment: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: to define and manage cron jobs, access to the operating system of the DB server is required. If you want _users_ to manage jobs like that, having a SQL (only) interface is usually easier to set up.